# Twitterizer - TwitterStatusCollectionResponse ResponseObject nothing

Tags: vb.net, twitterizer

I am trying to get the timeline of my user account so I can post the tweets on our website.  However, the TwitterStatusCollectionResponse ResponseObject is always nothing.  The Content property has what looks to be a valid json response.  The Result property is "Unknown".  Here is my code:

```
Dim tokens As New OAuthTokens()
    tokens.AccessToken = "XX"
    tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "XX"
    tokens.ConsumerKey = "XX"
    tokens.ConsumerSecret = "XX"

    Dim options As New SearchOptions()
    options.PageNumber = 2
    options.NumberPerPage = 2

    Dim timelineOptions As New TimelineOptions
    timelineOptions.IncludeRetweets = False
    timelineOptions.Count = 5


    Dim statusCollectionResponse As TwitterResponse(Of TwitterStatusCollection) = TwitterTimeline.HomeTimeline(tokens, timelineOptions)
'this next line errors.....
    For Each status In statusCollectionResponse.ResponseObject

    next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bet you got this version with nuget?  There have been problems with twitterizer via nuget for a while, mostly due to incompatible json.net versions.  I bet if you need it now you can get an older json.net and fix the issue for now.

Comment: I tried the older version of 4.0.5.0 and it didnt work.  What versions of each do I need?

Comment: I pulled down Newtonsoft.Json 3.5.0.0 and Twitterizer2 2.3.0 and it worked fine.  Thanks for answering that.  Yes, the nuget packages is how I got the original assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known bug that the author is fixing.
http://forums.twitterizer.net/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3721&p=5568&hilit=TwitterResponse+Of+TwitterStatusCollection+#p5568

I"ll wait for the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote this little test, it looks like it works just fine.
You can target the user using the UserId in the UerTimelineOptions
good luck.

```
'Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
'    Dim s As New UserTimelineOptions
'    s.Count = 3000
'    s.UseSSL = True
'    s.APIBaseAddress = "http://api.twitter.com/1/"
'    s.IncludeRetweets = False
'    s.UserId = 24769625
'    Dim T As TwitterResponse(Of TwitterStatusCollection) = TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(tokens, s)
'    For Each Tweet As TwitterStatus In T.ResponseObject
'        Console.WriteLine(Tweet.User.ScreenName & ": " & Tweet.Text)

'    Next

'End Sub
```